# NFTs minted by a safe are not indexed on OpenSea correctly (Polygon)

Tags: nft, gnosis-safe, opensea

There is an NFT contract (ERC1155): [0x45a30d068e3dc97f50948eda650d9c75de293b60](https://polygonscan.com/address/0x45a30d068e3dc97f50948eda650d9c75de293b60#code#F1#L18).

If I mint a token using EOA, the minting event is showing up on OpenSea as expected.

If a token is [minted by a safe](https://polygonscan.com/tx/0x3ea9fee00281198783691553e97c2d29bb14132b699939c7a57c7b19d1561b9c), the NFT is present on OpenSea, but the minting event is missing in the Item Activity section: [token](https://opensea.io/assets/matic/0xdf4429dbf4563306036672e99fa9e829889c9eb6/573384306318821075129873861604724969758)

TransferSingle (null -> msg.sender) event is there: [tenderly](https://dashboard.tenderly.co/tx/polygon/0x3ea9fee00281198783691553e97c2d29bb14132b699939c7a57c7b19d1561b9c/logs) .

[The token](https://rarible.com/token/polygon/0xdf4429dbf4563306036672e99fa9e829889c9eb6:573384306318821075129873861604724969758?tab=history) is handled by Rarible just fine.

Has anyone experienced this issue?

Comment: I think you should let OpenSea support know

Comment: Yep, I made a request, but "our responses can take up to a week"